# Angular data binding returning NaN or nothing

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-binding, angular8, two-way-binding

I have a input that before save, I want the input to display the value for A-B, and then I save this value with name count, after save, I run the fucntionA, and set the count as 5. But I am keep getting NaN as the result, I also tried to add type="number" in the html input tag, then it just display empty string noting inside the input field.

html file

```
<input type="number" [readonly]="true" class="abc" name="account" id="acc" [value]="A-B"  [(ngModel)]="count"/>
```

ts file

```
functionA(){
   this.count = 5;
   console.log(this.count); //5
   console.log(this.A - this.B); //5
}
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` is a two-way binding, so you don't need `[value]="A-B"` at all. The value will always be `this.count`

Comment: @JeremyThille but before I save, i want to display the value A-B, and A is a input value, so it would make the count dynamic.

Comment: You can't have _both_ a two-way data binding that sets the value to `count`, and also a one-way data binding that sets the value to `A-B` at the same time. It's simple common sense. I'm afraid you have to find another setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two-way binding and and input value.

You could try this for your html:

```
<input type="number" [readonly]="true" class="abc" name="account" id="acc" [(ngModel)]="difference"/>
```

and this for your .ts:

```
functionA(){
   this.count = 5;
   this.difference = this.A - this.B;
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but you could have one variable to hold the count, and another to hold the difference, and bind the difference to the input.